# How to check if I have properly installed Android SDK?

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I have installed Android SDK and Eclipse ADT plug-in for Android by following the directions from their website. I have also added the latest API and system images from the SDK manager. I have also made an AVD.

However, what I would like to know is **how do I confirm if I have done it right and that my future programs will work properly?**

What would be a *HelloWorld* of an Android project ?

**Update:**
As instructed, I tried making a blank activity and running it. Here is my console log:

```
[2013-06-30 02:12:55 - Hi] ------------------------------
[2013-06-30 02:12:55 - Hi] Android Launch!
[2013-06-30 02:12:55 - Hi] adb is running normally.
[2013-06-30 02:12:55 - Hi] Performing com.example.hi.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-06-30 02:12:55 - Hi] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2013-06-30 02:12:59 - Hi] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Trial'
[2013-06-30 02:13:07 - Hi] New emulator found: emulator-5556
[2013-06-30 02:13:07 - Hi] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
```

Comment: You could just try making File->New->Android->"Android Sample Project" and go through the wizard.

Comment: @daveychu It gets stuck at `Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...`

Comment: Have you installed Android Virtual Device? http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html

Comment: @daveychu Yes, I have made one for my Google Nexus 7 :-)

Comment: Does it pop up when you launch application? If it does, it might seem like the emulator gets 'stuck', but it just takes ages to load.

Comment: @daveychu I posted the console log :)

Comment: Did you launch the emulator first, before trying to run your application? I seem to recall having to start my emulator manually first.

Comment: @mustang2009cobra No, I did not do that !

Comment: Try that out and see if it works. By the way, the emulator takes forever to start up. It also took a long time for my app to actually get loaded and running on the emulator, so give it several minutes before you decide its not working.

Comment: @mustang2009cobra What am I supposed to get on the emulator if I run a blank activity ? Can you attach a screenshot with your answer ?

Comment: Hmm, I can't remember! Also, I"m not on the machine where I installed the Android dev tools, so I can't post a screenshot right this second. I'll try to later when I'm at that machine.

Comment: @mustang2009cobra I guess I am doing something wrong but dunno what: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384674/android-emulator-in-eclipse-does-not-work

Comment: Hmm not sure what could be going wrong. Have you tried following that tutorial step by step in the link I provided? That's what I did, and I didn't encounter any errors.

Comment: @mustang2009cobra I am planning to throw my PC out of the window. It launched. Too slowly ! :D

Comment: Haha I wouldn't throw your PC out the window just yet. I've heard numerous people complain about how slow the Android emulator is. The best option is to plug an android phone into your computer and launch apps on there. I don't know how to do that, though, cause I don't have an android phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just went through this process the other day! Here's the tutorial I used to do a "Hello World" Android app:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html