# Android emulator in Eclipse does not work?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have made a new AVD, created a new `Blank Activity`. The AVD is configured for `Android 4.2.2`, API level 17 and so is the blank activity.

However the log, when I run the activity, is this:

```
[2013-06-30 02:33:38 - myfirstapp] ------------------------------
[2013-06-30 02:33:38 - myfirstapp] Android Launch!
[2013-06-30 02:33:38 - myfirstapp] adb is running normally.
[2013-06-30 02:33:38 - myfirstapp] Performing com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-06-30 02:33:38 - myfirstapp] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2013-06-30 02:33:41 - myfirstapp] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'HelloEmulator'
[2013-06-30 02:33:48 - myfirstapp] New emulator found: emulator-5556
[2013-06-30 02:33:48 - myfirstapp] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
```

It launches some different, large-screen, emulator.
**What have I done wrong?**

Comment: What is the Resolution of your emulator and the size of your monitor or Display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two steps during launching your application with Android Virtual Device. First, launching the virtual device and second launching your application. If the virtual device is not already launched, it takes 3-4 min to be launched. During this step, the following message as you described above appears:

```
[2013-06-30 02:33:48 - myfirstapp] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
```

Launching application is faster than launching the android virtual device.

Answer (score 1):

evrey thing is going normal just wait
and to post emulator speed up you may check `use GPU host` and put ram size 850